# recursively convert files using ffmpeg in parallel

Tags: ffmpeg, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have the following two commands:

```
parallel --eta ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -i {} -c:a aac -b:a 64k {.}.aac ::: *
```

that converts all files (audio) in current folder to aac format in parallel (`file.mp3>file.aac`), and

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -i "{}" -c:a aac -b:a 64k "{}".aac' \;
```

that converts all files in all subdirectories to aac format (`file.mp3>file.mp3.aac`), but not in parallel.

So I want to accomplish two things:

1. execute command 2 in parallel
2. that the result is saved as in command 1, ie, `file.mp3>files.aac` instead of `file.mp3>file.mp3.aac`.

I've tried some combinations but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

I think I finally got it like this:

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.jpg" -not -name "*.png" -not -name "*.aac" -print0 | parallel -0 --eta ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -i {} -c:a aac -b:a 64k {.}.aac
```

Comment: Omit the `::: *` too.

Comment: I was confused because my Ubuntu machine had `parallel.moreutils` installed and taking over. Once I actually installed GNU parallel this worked great –